# How to fire a prototype event after another one has finished?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous

For example, doing this:

```
new Effect.Move('agrupador', { x: -100, y: 0, mode: 'relative' });
Element.setStyle('agrupador', {left: '0px' });
```

The left position is applied before the element moves left, but I want the opposite.

Is there any way of doing this?

PD: I will burn prototype, I promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/uF9Dh/

```
new Effect.Move('agrupador', {
    x: -100,
    y: 0,
    mode: 'relative',
    afterFinish: function() {
        Element.setStyle('agrupador', {left: '0px' });
    }
});
​
```

The move effect is asynchronous. When you call `new Effect.Move()`, you're setting up something to happen over the course of one second. In the code you posted, you set the `left` property to `0px` after you instantiated the effect, **not after the effect has finished**. There's an `afterFinish` callback for this purpose. You can check out the other available callbacks for Scriptaculous effects [here](http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/core-effects/).

BTW - This issue was not Prototype or Scriptaculous specific, but rather the way asynchronous actions in Javascript work.